# Why do some docker exec commands not always work in a batch file?

Tags: mysql, docker, powershell, batch-file, command-line

I can run a `docker exec` command that calls `mysql` fine in PowerShell:

```
docker exec -it my_container_name mysql -e "source my-query.sql" -uroot -pMyRootPassword
```

The container is running, the sql file is there, and the query runs successfully.

*But* when I copy and paste the exact same command into a `.bat` batch file that contains some other docker commands, and run it (via PowerShell), I get an error message "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket". If I put it into a *separate* batch file and run it on its own, it works fine.

There is a similar issue asked here - https://forums.docker.com/t/run-docker-exec-command-from-batch-file-in-windows-10/48163 - with no answer.

**More Detail:**

My complete batch file (simplified down) looks something like this:

```
set "container=my_container_name"
set "mysqlRootPassword=MyRootPassword"
docker stop %container%
docker rm %container%
docker run --name=%container% --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=%mysqlRootPassword%" --detach mariadb:10.5.6
docker exec -it %container% mysql -e "show databases;" -uroot -p%mysqlRootPassword%
```

When run this gives Error: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`. Everything above the `exec` runs OK.

Now if I run the *exact same exec command* in a *separate* batch file afterwards...

```
set "container=my_container_name"
set "mysqlRootPassword=MyRootPassword"
docker exec -it %container% mysql -e "show databases;" -uroot -p%mysqlRootPassword%
```

...Then it connects fine, the SQL command works fine, and shows the databases as expected.

Comment: your socket is not available, try -h127.0.0.1 so that mysql is forced to use tcp/ip

Comment: @nbk - Using `-h127.0.0.1` gives a similar error: "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)"

Comment: them when you start the command the docker hasn't startet

Comment: Like @PowerShellGuy, Add a `pause` after the `docker run ...` line and wait some seconds before pressing enter. If that works, you can replace the pause with some sleep command

Answer (score 2):

Hm, it looks like it may be a timing issue. Might be trying to exec into the container before the container is fully spun up. Try adding a sleep statement before the exec.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShellGuy is correct that it ended up being a timing issue. Apparently just because the docker container is up and running, it doesn't mean that the database is ready for connections. I solved the issue by adding a loop that waits and checks for a connection. There might be a better way to do this, but it solved my issue in the near term.

```bsh
set "container=my_container_name"
set "mysqlRootPassword=MyRootPassword"
docker stop %container%
docker rm %container%
docker run --name=%container% --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=%mysqlRootPassword%" --detach mariadb:10.5.6

for %%i in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7) ^
do (
    docker exec -it %container% mysql -e "show databases;" -uroot -p%mysqlRootPassword% && GOTO :connected || (
        @echo "Trying again (%%i)..."
        TIMEOUT 2
    )
)
@echo "Timed out"
EXIT

:connected
docker exec -it %container% mysql -e "source my-query.sql" -uroot -p%mysqlRootPassword%
```